# Elasticsearch NEST facet is tokenizing field even if attribute of NotAnalyzed is defined in the mapping

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am searching on `Event` objects in my elasticsearch index using NEST.  At its basic level, `Event` looks like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string EventType {get; set;}
}
```

My search looks like this:

```
SearchDescriptor<Event> search = new SearchDescriptor<Event>()
    .From(0)
    .Take(10000)
    .QueryRaw(@"{""match_all"": {} }")
    .FacetTerm("my_facet", f => f.OnField("eventType"));

var esResults = esClient.Search<Event>(search);
```

Currently, all of my documents in ES have an `eventType` of `Test type`, but the facet is returning results for `Test` and `type`, rather than returning them together.

My understanding is that the `Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed` is supposed to alleviate this issue, but I am still seeing it.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your index was created with proper mapping?

This code

```
var indicesOperationResponse = client.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor
    .Index(indexName)
    .AddMapping<Event>(m => m
        .MapFromAttributes()));
```

creates index with following mapping

```
{
    "my_index" : {
        "mappings" : {
            "event" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "eventType" : {
                        "type" : "string",
                        "index" : "not_analyzed"
                    },
                    "id" : {
                        "type" : "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your query works fine and returns correct facets:

```
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {..},
   "hits": {..},
   "facets": {
      "my_facet": {
         "_type": "terms",
         "missing": 0,
         "total": 3,
         "other": 0,
         "terms": [
            {
               "term": "Test type",
               "count": 3
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I have tested it against elasticsearch and NEST 1.5.0.

Comment: I did not explicitly call `CreateIndex` at any point.  Does that mapping need to be in place at index creation time?

Comment: You can take advantage of [put mapping api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html). Depends on your use case, post more details, so maybe I'll be able to tell something smarter.

Comment: I have a simple prototype for testing out ES in a product that previously used Solr.  I index with `ElasticClient.IndexMany()` and then I am searching as described in my question.

Comment: @Jim and `ElasticProperty` is ignored in your case. So elasticsearch created mapping with default setting your fields.

Comment: Why would `ElasticProperty` be ignored?  That's surprising to me

Comment: @Jim `ElasticProperty` attribute is using when you are explicitly create an index or set mapping for index. When you call `client.IndexMany(..)` without creating index, elasticsearch is taking care about index creation and mapping. So `ElasticProperty` is ignored.

Comment: Maybe this reading will be useful https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_creating_an_index.html